# Не могу передать переменную типа string через Intent

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public String abc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        abc="hello";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("abc", abc);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

//

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle passedDate = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(passedDate != null)
           String abc = passedDate.getString("abc","");
    }
}
```

Comment: getIntent().getStringExtra("abc");

Comment: спасибо работает

Comment: Как сделать подобное для Int  так не работает ?? (abc=getIntent().getIntExtra("abc");)

Comment: Чтобы получить int по такому принципу, нужно в скобках после названия переменной указать значение по умолчанию, которое будет присвоено переменной abc, если вдруг с переданным значением что-то не так (оно null, не того формата и т.д)

Comment: Для примера, так: abc = getIntent().getIntExtra("abc",1);

Comment: Cпасибо работает